# How to remove element from a raw array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that will push pop and display, but I cannot pop the pushed numbers in my program probably I can't delete the element of that array. This is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out
                .print("1.)Push\n2.)Pop\n3.)Display\n4.)Exit\n\nChoose Item :");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int[] a = new int[10];
        int b = 0;

        int i = 0;

        do
        {
            switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter Push number :");
                int v = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                a[b] = v;
                b += 1;

                System.out.print("Item push :" + v + "\n");

                System.out
                        .print("1.)Push\n2.)Pop\n3.)Display\n4.)Exit\n\nChoose Item :");
                x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

                if (x == 3) {
                    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
                        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 2:

                System.out.print("Enter Pop Number :");
                int c = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

                if (c == a[i]) {

                }

                System.out.print("Item Pop :" + c + "\n");

                System.out
                        .print("1.)Push\n2.)Pop\n3.)Display\n4.)Exit\n\nChoose Item :");
                x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

                if (x == 3) {
                    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
                        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
                    }
                }

                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            }

        } while (x == 1 || x == 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to pop from last or any number which user want??

Comment: yes for example i have pushed 2, 5, and 6 . then when i pop 2 and 6 then when i choose display the display will be 5 only.

Comment: Pop only works on the last item, so you will never be able to pop any item other than the last pushed

Comment: Can you give a more exact definition of your assignment? Usually pop does not pop a particular number but rather just gives the last pushed number. So what is the definition you have?

Comment: pop means using and deleting the last element

Comment: i see. but if i changed the pop into delete ? i just wanted to delete specific elements from the pushed array.

Comment: im sorry i will changed it into delete. hehe this is not my assignment i just wanted to do it.

Comment: It's worthwhile learning to use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

Comment: You can  do it by creating new array, but that is bad idea. if you delete multiple time then it will create extra overhead.

Comment: i will create new array then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to change the elements of an array, then you should not use an array.

If you really don't want to use containers, then you could allocate dynamically a new array without the element you want to remove (not so a good idea probably because of bad performance and wasted memory).

This could be the method that returns the new array:

```
public static int[] removeElementAt(int [] array, int index){
    if(index > 0 && index < array.length){
        int [] newArray = new int[array.length - 1];
        for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
            newArray[i] = array[i]; // copying elements
        for(int i=index+1; i<array.length; i++)
            newArray[i-1] = array[i];
        array = newArray;
    }
    return array;
}
```

This is just a simple example:

```
myArray = Class.removeElementAt(myArray, 5);  // removes 6. element
```

You could also use the function `removeElement` from the API [ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html), something like this:

```
array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element)
```

Another alternative would be to convert your array to a list, remove the element, and then convert it back to an array: not so a good idea, because you could use directly an `ArrayList`.

So, the idea is to use dynamic containers when you want to modify the content, otherwise use a normal raw array.

Answer (score 0):

When you push `2`, `5`, and `6` you have a queue with 3 items in it:

```
a[0] == 2
a[1] == 5
a[2] == 6
```

When you pop `2`, you want to remove it from the array. To do this, you need to copy everything after where `2` was popped from into the position above, so that you end up with:

```
a[0] == 5
a[1] == 6
```

The code for this would look something like:

```
int popPosition = findPopPosition();
for(int i = popPosition + 1; i < MAX; i++)
    a[i - 1] = a[i];
b--; // Decrease effective queue size
```

Where `findPopPosition()` would need to find the index that `2` is at, so it would return `0` in this example.

Or, alternatively, the user could input the pop position directly (so pop element `0`) instead of specifying what value they want to pop. That's probably more useful.

Comment: @shampoo The code I put in wasn't intended to be copy/pasted into your code. It was more of showing you what the idea of how it works is so that you have something to think about for coding it into your project. It would need the `findPopPosition()` to be defined, as well as the `MAX` defined, which right now you have hard-coded in your code to `10`

Comment: yeah i got it hmm iam trying to do it right now wait

Comment: when i am trying to pop in the index 0 it will show ArrayOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: @shampoo make sure you are doing `int i = popPosition + 1` and not just `popPosition`. Can you post the line that fails or the updated code?

Comment: yeah the problem is if i pop the number 6 it will be changed into 0 but not deleted in the display

Comment: @shampoo Are you wanting it to always display the entire array or just what's populated? So for the example of pushing `2`, `5`, and `6` then popping `2`. Do you want it to display `5`, `6` or do you want it to display `5`, `6`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `0`?

Comment: only the 5,6. i am using my index in the max so that it will displa y only the inputted indices

Comment: Oh okay, in your `pop` `case` you need a `b--;` if something was successfully popped. Editted in the answer to include decreasing the queue size.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code and it might solve your issue.

```
            int brr[]= new int [a.length-1];
               int j=0;
               for(;j<a.length;j++)
               {
                   if(c== a[j])
                   {
                       break;
                   }
                   else{
                       brr[j]=a[j];
                   }
               }
               for(j=j+1;j<a.length;j++)
               {
                 brr[j-1] =a[j];
               }
```

in display show brr array.

Comment: the problem is my pop will only change into 0 and it's not deleted

Comment: if you need to reduce the size also then you have to create another array.. after getting the value from user don't store that value in to new array

Answer (score 0):

Not all test cases have been handled, but a sample working program as per your requirements.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ArrayDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the Array Max Capacity");
        int maxSize = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        int[] array = new int[maxSize];
        int arrayCount = 0;
        int choice = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("\n1.Insert\n2.Delete\n3.Display\n4.Exit");
            choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                boolean insertTrue = insertElement(br, maxSize, array,
                        arrayCount);
                if (insertTrue) {
                    arrayCount++;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter Element to delete");
                int delElement = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
                int numOccurrence = getOccurrenceCount(array, arrayCount,
                        delElement);

                int newArrayCount = arrayCount - numOccurrence;
                if (numOccurrence == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No Such Element to delete");
                } else {
                    array = deleteElement(array, arrayCount, delElement,
                            newArrayCount,maxSize);

                }
                arrayCount =newArrayCount;
                break;
            case 3:
                displayArray(array, arrayCount);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Exiting");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice, Exiting");
                choice = 4;
            }
        } while (choice >= 1 && choice <= 3);
    }

    private static int[] deleteElement(int[] array, int arrayCount,
            int delElement, int newArrayCount,int maxSize) {
        int newArray[] = new int[newArrayCount];
        int index=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
            if (array[i] != delElement) {
                newArray[index] = array[i];
                index++;
            }
        }
        resetArray(array, maxSize);
        for(int i=0;i<newArrayCount;i++){
            array[i]=newArray[i];
        }
        return array;
    }

    private static int[] resetArray(int[] array,int maxSize){
        for(int i=0;i<maxSize;i++){
            array[i]=0;
        }
        return array;
    }

    private static int getOccurrenceCount(int[] array, int arrayCount,
            int delElement) {
        int numOccurrence = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
            if (array[i] == delElement) {
                numOccurrence++;
            }
        }
        return numOccurrence;
    }

    private static void displayArray(int[] array, int arrayCount) {
        if (arrayCount == 0) {
            System.out.println("No Elements to Display");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Array is");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
                System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    private static boolean insertElement(BufferedReader br, int maxSize,
            int[] array, int arrayCount) throws IOException {
        if (arrayCount < maxSize) {
            System.out.println("Enter Element for Insertion");
            array[arrayCount] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Max Limit Reached, Insertion not possible");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```